# anaconda installing graph-tool on windows error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, graph-tool

I am trying to install graph-tool with anaconda. This is how I went about that:

```
conda config --add channels jithinpr2
```

followed by

```
conda install -c jithinpr2 graph-tool=2.18
```

The second command gives the following error:

```
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - graph-tool 2.18*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I tried to follow their instructions and do `conda info graph-tool` and `conda info graph-tool=2.18`, but both resulted in:

```
Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - graph-tool 2.18*
```

What am I doing wrong? I am running python 2.7 by the way.

Comment: Debugging conda issues always tricky.  I am curious about the name of the file that is on your channel: `win-64/win-64_linux-64_graph-tool-2.18-py27_3.tar.bz2`  I would have expected that file to be `win-64/win-64_graph-tool-2.18-py27_3.tar.bz2 (i.e. without the extra `linux-64_`) in the file.  Have you posted to the conda google group or asked in the gitter channel? https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/conda https://gitter.im/conda/conda https://gitter.im/conda/conda-build